# Fit UITableview within Scrollview

Tags: iphone

I created an application using a `UITableview`.

But when I scroll the table view, I see a white space view before and after the table view. How can I fit the `UITableview` so it doesn't show that empty view?

Here's an image of what happens when I scroll the UITableview.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is...

```
tableView.bounces=FALSE;
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the `bounces` property of the UITableView to `FALSE`.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html%23//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIScrollView

(UITableView inherits from UIScrollView)